# Horizontal scrollview inside another horizontalscroll view in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm designing UI in **react native** where I've a `HorizontalScrollView` inside another `HorizontalScrollView`. However, the child `HorizontalScrollView` doesn't work.

Is it possible to disable the parent `HorizontalScrollView` whenever a gesture is made in child `HorizontalScrollView`. I know this sounds tricky but I need to implement this in my UI.

**note**: working fine in IOS

**code snippet**:

```
import React from 'react';
        import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView, 
        TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Image, Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';
        import Carousel, { Pagination } from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
        import { Input, Button, Divider, Card, Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';

        export default class Cart extends React.Component {
          state = {
            data: [
                { title: 'a', url: require("./Light-Hover34x34.png") },
                { title: 'b', url: require("./Light-Hover34x34.png") },
                { title: 'c', url: require("./Light-Hover34x34.png") },
                { title: 'd', url: require("./Light-Hover34x34.png") },
                { title: 'e', url: require("./Light-Hover34x34.png") },
            ],
            activeSlide: 0,
            room: ["one", "two", "three"]
        }

        _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
            console.log("active slide", this.state.activeSlide)
            const isActive = index === this.state.activeSlide;

            return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                // onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.url)}
                style={{
                backgroundColor: isActive ? '#FFD845' : null,
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                borderRadius: 60/2,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Image
                    source={item.url}
                    style={{ width: '50%', height: '40%' }}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
            );
         };

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', paddingVertical: 100}}>
                  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                    {
                      this.state.room.map((r, i) => {
                        return(
                          <View key={i}>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                              <Card containerStyle={[styles.cardEleBig,]}>
                                  <SafeAreaView style={{ height: 150 }}>
                                      <Carousel
                                          data={this.state.data}
                                          renderItem={this._renderItem}
                                          sliderWidth={120}
                                          itemWidth={50}
                                          onSnapToItem={index => this.setState({ activeSlide: index })} //for pagination
                                      />
                                  </SafeAreaView>
                                </Card>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                          </View>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
            );
          }
        }

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          cardCircleParking: {
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            // marginBottom: 10,
            // marginLeft: '5%',
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            borderRadius: 50/2,
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
        cardEleBig: {
          borderRadius: 20,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          borderColor: 'white',
          width: 159,
          height: Platform == "ios" ? 210 : 200,
          shadowColor: "#000",
          shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 2,
          },
          shadowOpacity: 0.25,
          shadowRadius: 3.84,
          elevation: 5,
          marginLeft: 5,
          marginRight: 5,
          marginTop: 10,
          marginBottom: 2
        },
        })
```

But this code is working fine with IOS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: thanks for reply. please can you run this expo snack in your android phone. https://snack.expo.io/@sagar293/flatlist-inside-scrollview

Comment: hi @WaLinke have you checked it out?